# Catch the name from an object argument as a string

Tags: javascript

It must be something easy; however I cannot find it...

```
function isDOM(obj)
{   
    if (obj.nodeType!==undefined)
        console.log(obj,' is DOM element');
    else
      console.log(obj,' is not DOM element');
}
```

The above function checks if object obj is a member or not of DOM. However, I want a reply like that:

```
document.body is DOM element
```

by calling `isDOM(document.body);` How may I catch the string '**document.body**' as to pass it inside console.log and get exactly the argument name to the console?

Thank you

Comment: it's not possible without using a second argument that describe the name

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? like adding expected output?

Comment: @rajuGT: It's already in the question: *"However, I want a reply like that: `document.body is DOM element`"*